# ¿Porque no puedo instalar Glassfish en NetBeans 8.2?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2, glassfish

Me sale el siguiente error al tratar de instalar el servidor glassfish en netbeans:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿A que se deberá?

Comment: Se que una forma de arreglar esto es actualizar el netBeans, otra era cambiar el nombre del archivo .jar de glash .... pero si mal no recuerdo la segunda opción no era muy viable porque tenias que repetir esto cada vez que abres netbeans,

Comment: Veo que estás haciendo preguntas y que tienes respuestas, pero no estás marcando ninguna como correcta ni dando ningún feedback. Te recomiendo que revises el [tour] para que repases como funciona este sitio.